# Ionic V1 scanbarcode's plugin don't return data to page

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, barcode-scanner

I have the following controller

```
    $scope.scanBarcode = function (nombre) {
        $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function (result) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $scope[nombre] = result.text;
            }, 1000);

        }, function (error) {
            alert("An error happened -> " + error);
        });
    };
```

The view to show the result is the following

```
   <label class="item item-input" id="page-input5">
    <span class="input-label">Input</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="" ng-model="xxx">
  </label>
  <button id="page-button1" class="button button-positive button-block" ng-click="scanBarcode('xxx')">Enviar</button>
```

When it scans the bar code, it does it several times, but never returns the data to the model.

Is there an error in the code? reference https://github.com/adamweeks/ion-scanner

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Did you forget $ionicPlatform.ready() ??

Comment: I just added it, and still no data is returned to the model